# Getting error in if clause in shell script inside jenkins job

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, sh

I am having shell script like this

```
while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do
noStudent="false"
LINE=$(echo "$LINE" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
if [ $LINE == "myname" ]
then
noStudent="true"
fi

if [ $noStudent == "true" ]
then
  #DO SOME STUFF
fi
done < Teachers
```

But I am getting error on each line when files is read :

```
+ [ yourname == myname ]
/tmp/hudson433507028658734743.sh: 20: [: yourname: unexpected operator
+ [ false == true ]
/tmp/hudson433507028658734743.sh: 26: [: false: unexpected operator
```

What can be the reason for it ? Please help. Am not able to figure out.

Comment: try http://www.shellcheck.net/ for errors. You do need to quote your environment variables e.g. "$LINE"

Answer (score 2):

Your script isn't actually being executed by `bash`, but by some other shell linked to by `/bin/sh` (likely `dash`, see below). The POSIX standard does not recognize `==` as a valid operator with the `[` command; you need to use `=` instead.

Using `dash`, for example, this can be reproduced with

```
$ [ foo == foo ] && echo same
dash: 5: [: foo: unexpected operator
$ [ foo = foo ] && echo same
same
$
```

You will almost certainly use `[` because you are concerned about portability, in which case you must also use `=`. If you aren't concerned about portability, and your shell allows `==` inside `[`, you can almost certainly (and probably should) use `[[` instead.